# converting udf to an inline lambda in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame  that consists of 4 columns. Let's say it's A, B, C and D. I want to exclude rows where column B has value of 'NONE' or 'NOTHING'. I know how to do this using UDF, but I'm curious how to do this in a lambda anonymous function instead.

My DataFrame is df, and my udf is as follow:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
def B_field(B_field_value):
   if B_field_value == 'NONE' or B_field_value == 'NOTHING':
      return True
udf_B = udf(B_field, BooleanType())
print df.filter(udf_CT(df['B'])).count()
```

I'm trying to do it the lambda way, and i can't get this to work

```
df.select(df['CT']).filter(lambda x: x == 'NONE' or x == ''NOTHING)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to [spark guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) the format is:

```
df.filter(df['age'] > 21).show()
```

In your case you can use one of the following filter conditions:

```
df.filter((df['CT'] != 'NOTHING') && df['CT'] != 'None'))
```

`where` condition (which is an alias for `filter`):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col 

df.where(
    (col('CT') != 'NOTHING') &&
    (col('CT') != 'NONE'))
```

or:

```
df.filter(col("CT").notEqual("NOTHING") && col("CT").notEqual("NONE"))
```